# Python program that calculates ideal presidential candidate based on position data?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a python program that helps people determine the best democratic presidential candidate by comparing their positions with those of the candidates.

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
    Issue1  Issue2
biden   yes no
booker  no  yes
sanders no  no
```

The idea is to create another column in the data frame to contain the scores for each candidate such as `df['candidate_score']`.

The scores for each issue are generated by first asking the user about their personal stance on the issue.

For example, "Do you support the Green New Deal? Yes/No" -- if the user input matches the candidate stance (as contained in the DataFrame), then the variable polarity is 1, else -1.

The next question assesses the importance of the current issue. For example, "On a scale of 0-10, how important to you is the Green New Deal issue?"

So, if someone agrees with the candidate (positive polarity) and rates the issue as being 10 important, then the score for that question would be 10.

Or, if someone disagrees with the candidate (negative polarity) but it's not an important issue (e.g., 2), then the score would be -2.

I want to then be able to ask another question based a a different issue and have that score appended to the `df['candidate_score']` column to get a running total.

Once all the questions have been answered by the user, I'd like to print the top X candidates.

Can someone please give me some ideas as to where to start with a program like this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how you will obtain the data, but if you continue with the first piece of data and fit everyone into a yes or no on all relevant issues you could then find which one is most similar to the popular opinion on each issue. This would give you, roughly, the most popular candidate. Although, there are clear issues with this use of data with respect to obtaining "the best candidate". For instance, many people don't look at/consider policies when voting. That alone "destroys" any model to determine the best candidate based in policy stances. Or at least that's what I think initially.

Comment: This sounds similar to 'content-based recommendation' approach.

Link: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/08/beginners-guide-learn-content-based-recommender-systems/

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of similarity scoring functions out there from which you may choose.
A simple one is the euclidean distance.

Your first quick and dirty solution should be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

candidates = ['Bennet', 'Biden', 'Booker', 'Bullock', 'Buttigieg', 'Castro',
'de Blasio', 'Delaney', 'Gabbard', 'Gillibrand', 'Harris', 'Inslee', 'Klobuchar',
'Messam', 'Moulton', 'O’Rourke', 'Ryan', 'Sanders', 'Sestak', 'Steyer', 'Warren', 
'Williamson', 'Yang', 'Trump', 'Weld']
NUM_ISSUES = 30

# Gauge opinion by 1-10 (disagree - agree, 5=neutral) ratings?
PREF_RNG = 10

issue_names = [f'issue {i}' for i in range(NUM_ISSUES)]

def random_score_vec(num_issues, pref_rng):
    # 0 - 1 random vector
    r = np.random.rand(num_issues)

    # change to prefered range
    r = r * pref_rng
    return r.astype(int)

candidate_positions = pd.DataFrame({c:random_score_vec(NUM_ISSUES, PREF_RNG) for c in candidates},
                                    index=issue_names)

display(candidate_positions)

# Individual preferences can be inserted as a list
# at the place where we call the random scores
individual_answers = pd.Series(
                        random_score_vec(NUM_ISSUES, PREF_RNG), 
                        index=issue_names)
# Reformat the answers into a transposed vector
y = np.expand_dims(individual_answers, axis=0)

score_vals = euclidean_distances(y, candidate_positions.values.T)[0]

# Stretch out / normalize scores 
score_vals = (score_vals - min(score_vals)) / (max(score_vals) - min(score_vals))
score_df = pd.Series(score_vals,
                     index=candidates,
                     name='Scores').sort_values()
print(score_df)
```

A select few of the similarity scoring functions are given by sklearn here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics.pairwise